# Hello, tried to create TableView, but nothing is showing

Tags: swift, storyboard, tableview, cell, display

here is the code which is connected to TableView.

```
import UIKit

class CountryCodeVC: UITableViewController {
    
    let array = ["Canada"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountryCell", for: indexPath )
            cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: If you implement `viewDidLoad` you have to call `super`. But in this case you can delete the method because `dataSource` and `delegate` are connected by default in `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good. Can You check if the `reuseIdentifier` for your cell is typed the same way as you called it in the `storyboard` ?

You should click on that cell.

[image]

and next u should name it inside that field.

[image]